# Why cannot return correct array of dynamic size in C++?

Tags: c++

### My Problem:

I got some problem when I return the pointer `float data` in code below.

How could print the same output `1  4` in `CodeA` and `CodeB`.

### Description:

In `CodeA`, `data` has been declared to an n*n float array. And assigned by some values.

Then print them will get correct values.

In `CodeB`, `arr` is an float pointer. It's the return array from function `get2dArrayData`.

Then print them will get incorrect values. (Seems like overflow?)

---

**CodeA: Output is '1  4'.**

```
float * Application::get2dArrayData(int n) {
  float data[n * n];

  ... // Assign something (data[0] = 1, data[1] = 4, ...) here.

  // Print data here.
  cout << data[0] << "  " << data[1] << endl;

  return data;
}
```

---

**CodeB: Output is like '2.8026e-45  6.03325e-34'.**

```
void Application::main() {
  float * arr = this->get2dArrayData(5);

  // Print data here.
  // But got error memory address.
  cout << arr[0] << " " << arr[1] << endl;

  return;
}
```

---

And I try to add `static` for `data` in `CodeA`.

```
static float data[n * n];
```

Will show this error message.

```
error: variable length array declaration cannot have 'static' storage duration
       static float data[n * n];
                         ^^^^^
```

Comment: The duplicate answered your question, but you should know that VLA are not standard `C++`, even if they exist in `C`

Comment: Use a `std::vector<float> data(n * n);` and return that. That is how dynamic arrays are managed in C++.

Comment: Dear @juanchopanza , I add some problem description in the bottom.

Comment: Yes, you have more than one problem in your code. The duplicate deals with one, so you can start be thinking how to fix that one.

Comment: Don't use non standard c++ features, and you'll have less things to worry about. Galik gave you the best advice. Return a `std::vector` instead of a `float *`.